# Sangaku: to prove one of the intangents is parallel to $BC$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, sangaku

Given an acute triangle $\triangle ABC$ whose incircle is $I(r)$. Let $O(R)$ be the circle through $B$ and $C$ and which touches $I(r)$ interiorly. Show that the circle $P(p)$ which is tangent to $AB$, $AC$ and $O(R)$ (externaly) is such that one intagent line from $P(p)$ and $I(r)$ is parallel to side $BC$.

[image]

I have seen a couple solutions for this online but I never really understood them and they all seem wrong to me. For example, this is the problem 2 in [here](http://forumgeom.fau.edu/FG2010volume10/FG201002.pdf). The solution they give doesn't ring a bell. When they say that $\angle ACB - \angle ADE = \angle AED - \angle ABC$ (which is correct) and then they claim that  $\angle ADE < \angle ACB$ and $\angle AED > \angle ABC$ imply that $\angle ADE=\angle ABC$ it just sounds wrong. They could just use the congruence of $ADE$ and $AFG$ but instead they use this confuse argument.

And things get worse after the co-axial system. They give a huge jump and conclude that $BCD'E'$ is cyclic. This is best solution I have found for this problem but I just can't agree with it.

Comment: They claim $FG \parallel BC\implies \angle ADE=\angle ABC,$ not that $\angle ADE=\angle ABC$ always.  Are you saying that sounds wrong?

Comment: what sounded wrong is that they claimed that this implication came from the two inequalities. Did I interpret it wrong? It came from the congruence, but the main problem is to show that $BCD'E'$ is cyclic.

Comment: There seems to be a more-general principle involved here. Ignore the incircle context, and consider disjoint circles $p$ & $q$, with circle $r$ tangent to both (internally, externally, whatever). Then, according to some ugly coordinate-bashing in Mathematica, I believe we can say this: *When $r$ meets the **external** tangents of $p$ & $q$ in four points, two of the resulting chords in $r$ are parallel to the **internal** tangents of $p$ & $q$; and vice-versa.* (The result in question corresponds to a special circumstance where a chord of $r$ happens to be tangent to one of the other circles.)

Comment: this must be a theorem and I shall find it's name

Comment: @Blue, that is a very nice observation. Presumably if the referenced Unger proof is correct it should generalize to your observation.  Or it may be easier to prove more directly starting from the textbook method of constructing tangent circles using secants from a center of similitude.

Comment: You say "Sangaku" problem (I know what it means) : where have you found it ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I don't recall the exact page it was like a month ago and I couldn't find on Google it was similar to the one i linked here: a bunch of sangakus solved and this one solved incorrectly too. Even more incorrectly than the above.

Comment: The author has written another [Sangaku Problems paper](https://cpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/u.osu.edu/dist/8/3390/files/2014/04/Sangaku-12zn2jo.pdf).  Solution 16 is meant to supersede the 2010 paper.  Not sure whether it clears up anything here tho.

Comment: @brainjam I think that is the first pdf I was looking for lol. This is the one which has a worst solution for the problem, iirc problem 5 is not properly solved as well. I'm not trying to roast the author, most of results are correct I just think this problem is simply not solved anywhere. We need to find the name of Blue's theorem.

Comment: @brainjam , the link to the paper in your comment is broken. Do you still have it?

Comment: @ACB .. the broken link version is at https://web.archive.org/web/20180121080611/https://u.osu.edu/unger.26/files/2014/04/Sangaku-12zn2jo.pdf

Comment: Thank you @brainjam. I got [2021 edition](https://u.osu.edu/unger.26/online-publications/sangaku-problems-involving-ellipses/). Seemingly, that answer is not updated. Also that proof is wrong. At one point, they incorrectly use the fact as a data, which is the one we have to prove.

Comment: @ACB .. yes, hellofriends said it was a worse proof than the 2010 version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Proof**

Please consider this <s>messy</s> diagram.

[image]

Suppose that the radical axis of $c_1$ and $c_2$ intersects the bigger circle at $O$. From the definition of the radical axis, the tangents from $O$ to $c_1$ and $c_2$, namely $OP$ and $OQ$, are equal in length.

For clarification, $BE,$ $CD,$ $BF,$ $CT$ are the tangents to $c_1$ and $c_2$ as depicted in the picture. Also the internal tangent of those two circles $(\overleftrightarrow{RS})$ intersects the bigger circle at $M$ and $N$.

Now we use [Casey's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casey%27s_theorem).

First, considering $O,N,c_1,M$ and $O,N,M,c_2$.

$$ON\cdot MR+OM\cdot NR=OP\cdot MN$$
$$ON\cdot MS+OQ\cdot MN=OM\cdot NS$$

Add the two equations,

$$ON\cdot\underbrace{(MR+MS)}_{RS}=OM\cdot\underbrace{(NS-NR)}_{RS}$$
$$\implies ON=OM.$$

That means $O$ is the midpoint of $\overset{\huge\frown}{MN}.$

Similarly, applying Casey's theorem to $O,B,C,c_1$ and $O,B,C,c_2$ we get

$$OC=OB.$$

Therefore $O$ is also the midpoint of $\overset{\huge\frown}{BC}.$

Hence, $NM\parallel BC.$ $~~~\square$

Answer (score 2):

The proof of the theorem is simply wrong.  It incorrectly asserts that the points of tangency of $\odot O$ with $\odot I$ and $\odot P$ are located at $D'$ and $E'$, respectively.  This is impossible, because $DE$ is tangent to $\odot I$ and $\odot P$ at $D'$ and $E'$, respectively, thus if $\odot O$ is tangent to $\odot I$ and $\odot P$ at these same points, $\odot O$ is tangent to line $DE$ at two distinct points--impossible, unless $D' = E'$ which implies $\triangle ABC$ is isosceles.  Refer to the figure:

[image]

To be precise, the claim presented in the theorem is true; however, the proof is incorrect.  If one is not convinced, we can draw the diagram on the Cartesian plane and explicitly calculate the relevant coordinates.

Comment: Your argument made sense but the figure in my question was draw following their steps. I'll check the figure again, but what you wrote does make sense to me

Comment: @hellofriends You need to draw the figure *very* precisely to see the error.  I will upload a figure in a future edit to my answer.  Again, the claim in the theorem is true, but the circle that is tangent in the way described doesn't pass through $D'$ or $E'$.

Comment: I think your last conclusion may be wrong: just because $O$ is in the angle bisector and the perpendicular bisector doesn't mean ABC is isosceles, because $O$ is not circumcente and line $DE$ would not be a tangent line in the circle $O$

Comment: I need some time

Comment: @hellofriends Consider the second argument I provided, which I think is simpler.

Comment: checked it and you are correct!That proof was very weird to me indeed.

Comment: @hellofriends: $\odot O$ isn't tangent to $DE$.  So there's no contradiction.

Comment: @brainjam but the construction did generate two distinct points and the first argument does prove that $E',D',O,P$ are colinear

Comment: @hellofriends If by the first argument you mean the one that has been deleted, it is incorrect in step 2 because $\angle PE'X$ is not a right angle.  That's because $E'$ is different from the point where the intangent touches.

Comment: $E'$ is defined as the point in which the tangent line touches the circle centered at $P$. Therefore, as $X$ is in this tangent line that angle should be a right angle. The solution  claims that the circle $O$ is also tangent at $P$ on $E'$. And again, when I draw it it had two points of contact.

Comment: @hellofriends yes, you're right, I missed that.  I'm beginning to agree that the proof is incorrect at that point.  It seems to assume that the touch points of the intangent with (P) and (I) are the touch points of (O) with those circles - as heropup points out.

Answer (score 2):

As @Blue has pointed out in the comments,

> Ignore the incircle context, and consider disjoint circles $p$ & $q$,
> with circle $r$ tangent to both (internally, externally, whatever).
> Then, according to some ugly coordinate-bashing in Mathematica, I
> believe we can say this: *When $r$ meets the **external tangents** of $p$ &
> $q$ in four points, two of the resulting chords in $r$ are parallel to
> the **internal tangents** of $p$ & $q$; and vice-versa.* (The result in
> question corresponds to a special circumstance where a chord of $r$
> happens to be tangent to one of the other circles.)

There's an interesting discussion of this claim at [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/284458/5687).  In particular, [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/304296/5687) cites Gueron's [*Two Applications of the Generalized Ptolemy Theorem*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2695499), where it is referred to and proven as the Parallel Tangent Theorem.

Comment: I like "Blue's Theorem" better. ;)  Good sleuthing! ... And now I don't have to bother cleaning-up my own proof.

Comment: It may be Casey theorem

Comment: @hellofriends .. I remember wondering why you thought Casey's theorem applied.  But you were right!

Comment: yeah, in my head this "Blue theorem" was a specific case of Caseys's theorem which would be enough. I couldn't imagine Casey's theorem was stronger than this. It seems to have some very interesting applications.